# Show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{a_n}{n^s} = l\zeta(s) + o(\zeta(s))$ where $\lim \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_n= l$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a real sequence. We suppose thar $\lim \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_n = l \in \Bbb R$.

Show that as $s \rightarrow 1^+$, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{a_n}{n^s} = l\zeta(s) + o(\zeta(s))$$

Where $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^s}$

---

**What I did :** 
I showed that the serie $\sum a_n$ converges using summation by parts.

**What I tried :**
I don't know how to start

Comment: What have you tried ? Have you been able to prove that $\sum_{n} \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ converges ? It's not obvious.

Comment: Yes I've proved it already, using summation by parts

Comment: Letting $b_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_n$, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s} -l \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left( \frac{(b_n-b_{n-1})n}{n^s} + \frac{b_{n-1}-l}{n^s}\right) $$ $\dfrac{b_{n-1}-l}{n^s}$ is easy to take care of, but $\dfrac{(b_n-b_{n-1})n}{n^s}$ isn't... It might be useful to note that $(b_n-b_{n-1})n = a_n - b_{n-1}$, but I don't think one can get a nice estimate on this last difference without any further assumption.

Comment: I don't know... There's no further assumption in my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abel's sum formula is very helpful in matters concerning Dirichlet series. Let

$$A(x) = \sum_{n \leqslant x} a_n,$$

then Abel's sum formula gives

$$\sum_{n \leqslant x} \frac{a_n}{n^s} = \frac{A(x)}{x^{s}} + s\int_1^x \frac{A(t)}{t^{s+1}}\,dt$$

and for $s > 1$ we obtain

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^s} = s\int_1^{\infty} \frac{A(t)}{t^{s+1}}\,dt\,.$$

The assumption on the $a_n$ says that $A(x) = l\cdot x + o(x)$, and therefore

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^s} = s\int_1^{\infty} \frac{l\cdot t + o(t)}{t^{s+1}}\,dt = ls\int_1^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t^s} + s\int_1^{\infty} \frac{o(1)}{t^s}\,dt = \frac{ls}{s-1} + o\bigl(\lvert s-1\rvert^{-1}\bigr)\,.$$

Since $\zeta(s) = \frac{s}{s-1} + O(1)$ as $s \to 1$, the assertion follows.

Comment: How did you turn $\int_1^{+\infty} \dfrac{o(1)}{t^s} \textrm{d}t$ into $o\left(\dfrac{1}{\mid s - 1\mid}\right)$, shouldn't be some $o\left(\dfrac{s}{s - 1}\right)$ in order to get $o(\zeta(s))$ ?

Comment: The absence or presence of the factor $s$ is irrelevant, since we look at $s\to 1^+$ (since we don't know whether $\sum \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ has a meromorphic continuation to a neighbourhood of $1$ we must restrict the way we approach $1$, but we could allow non-real $s$ with $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$, as long as $\frac{\lvert s-1\rvert}{\operatorname{Re} s - 1}$ remains bounded). To get the $o()$ out of the integral, choose $\varepsilon > 0$ and a $t_0$ such that $\lvert o(1)\rvert < \varepsilon$ for $t > t_0$, then split the integral at $t_0$. $\int_1^{t_0} o(1)t^{-s}\,dt$ is entire, and

Comment: $$\Biggl\lvert \int_{t_0}^{\infty} \frac{o(1)}{t^s}\,dt\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon \int_1^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t^{\operatorname{Re} s}} = \frac{\varepsilon}{\operatorname{Re} s - 1}\,.$$

Comment: Do you think the $\epsilon -A$ approach is tractable ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon What is the $\epsilon-A$ approach?

Comment: @DanielFischer $\epsilon-\delta$ sorry. Proving that $$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta, s\in (1,1+\delta)\implies \left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s} -l \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}\right| \leq \epsilon \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$$

Comment: @GabrielRomon Yes, when one fills in the details I outlined, that's what one gets. One can also do it via summation by parts keeping it in sum form, rather than writing it as an integral. But avoiding a summation by parts will be ugly.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've added an answer that follows this path.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to prove that $$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta, s\in (1,1+\delta)\implies \left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s} -l \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}\right| \leq \epsilon \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$$
Letting $b_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_n$, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s} -l \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left( \frac{b_n-b_{n-1}}{n^{s-1}} + \frac{b_{n-1}-l}{n^s}\right)$$

Summation by part yields $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b_n-b_{n-1}}{n^{s-1}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n\left(\frac{1}{n^{s-1}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-1}} \right)$.

By the mean value theorem, for each $n$, there is some $x_n\in (n,n+1)$ such that $$\frac{1}{n^{s-1}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-1}} = \frac{s-1}{x_n^{s}}$$

Thus $$\left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s} -l \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}\right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left| \frac{b_n(s-1)}{x_n^{s}}\right| + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{b_{n-1}-l}{n^s}\right|$$

---

Since $b_n$ converges, it is bounded by some $M$, and $x_n> n$, thus $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left| \frac{b_n(s-1)}{x_n^{s}}\right|\leq M(s-1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^s} $$

Using integrals, one easily shows that $\zeta(s)\leq \frac{1}{s-1} +1$, hence $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left| \frac{b_n(s-1)}{x_n^{s}}\right|\leq Ms$$

---

Since $b_n$ converges to $l$, there is some $N$ such that $n\geq N\implies |b_n-l|\leq \epsilon$.

Then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{b_{n-1}-l}{n^s}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left|\frac{b_{n-1}-l}{n^s}\right| +\epsilon\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}= \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\left|b_{n-1}-l\right|-1}{n^s} +\epsilon\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s} $$

---

To finish the proof, note that $\lim_{s\to 1^+} \zeta(s) = \infty$, so the bound $$\left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s} -l \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}\right|\leq \underbrace{Ms + \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\left|b_{n-1}-l\right|-1}{n^s}}_{\text{has a finite limit}} +\epsilon\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$$
does the job.